# Did the Sanhedrin ever convene at night or on holidays?

Tags: beit-din-court, evening-night

Were there ever any times or special circumstances in either Temple period where the Sanhedrin would convene on Shabbat, at night or on holidays?

Comment: Someone voted to close because of comparitive religion. How does this fall into that category? Just because the NT _happens_ to mention the Sanhedrin convening at night and on a holiday when they weren't supposed to doesn't mean a.) that was the OP's motives in asking the question - and b.) it's a bad question.

Comment: Perhaps the OP could add why it might be thought possible or give a Jewish reference.

Comment: @sabba That might improve the question, but that doesn’t mean it’s off topic if the OP doesn’t.

Comment: Wouldn't they have to convene to sanctify the new moon if rosh chodesh came out on shabbos?

Comment: @Nic I think that people assume that the question means for judgement which was why called it the reference to the other religion.

Comment: The motive for asking the question is to shed light on the NT portrayal of the Sanhedrin convening at night on Pesach in order to question and accuse j-sus of crimes. Seems highly unlikely the high court would meet on Pesach so the NT account must be a fabrication. There is no intent of comparative religion in this question. Just seeking facts from the Judaic POV regarding the Sanhedrin during the second Beis Hamikdash era.